# Alignment Text View trouble?

Tags: iphone, xcode, alignment

When I add a `UITextView` and I fill it with words, then I go to **Attribute inspector** and set its text Alignment to Left by clicking the first option as you can see in the picture below. It works properly but if I try to align the text to **center** or I try to set its alignment as **Justify** as shown in the picture below, it gives me an error.

Does anyone know why?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEz2k.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add the error's screenshot in your question?

Comment: There it is http://oi66.tinypic.com/20gjml0.jpg ... I guess

Comment: another one http://oi64.tinypic.com/dqgimh.jpg

Comment: It's showing bad access. Issue isn't your UITextViewAlignment. Issue is you are accessing variable which has been released or something else. Click on the play button right next to your breakpoint button to print logs in console.

Comment: I mixed, I can't the logs in the play button, I can see (play, text, profile and analyze) I am using Xcode 6.1.1